# spreading the dataset on selected columns without any identifier

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to spread the dataset using few selected columns in which there are no unique identifiers to identify the rows. For this, I am using the publicly available iris dataset.

I have tried by removing the unwanted columns first and then creating the unique values without any duplicates. Later applying the spread on top of it.

```
iris %>% select(-c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% unique() %>% 
  spread(Species, Sepal.Length)
iris %>% select(-c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% unique() %>% 
  spread(key=Species, value=Sepal.Length)
```

But it gives the below duplicate identifiers errors:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
>   11, 12, 13, 14, 15), (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
>   28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36), (37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
>   45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57)

using `row_number()`, have created a unique identifier so as to use while spreading the data and avoid error duplicate rows message.

```
iris %>% select(-c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% unique() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% spread(Species, Sepal.Length)
```

which gives the below output:

```
#    row setosa versicolor virginica
# 1    1    5.1         NA        NA
# 2    2    4.9         NA        NA
# 3    3    4.7         NA        NA
# ...
# 16  16     NA        7.0        NA
# 17  17     NA        6.4        NA
# 18  18     NA        6.9        NA
# ...
# 37  37     NA         NA       6.3
# 38  38     NA         NA       5.8
# 39  39     NA         NA       7.1
```

However, due to the row numbers, there are many NAs which is not expected. I tried to remove the `row` number so as to get the values as expected, but it did not materialize.

```
iris %>% select(-c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% unique() %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  spread(Species, Sepal.Length, -row)

iris %>% select(-c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% unique() %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  spread(Species, Sepal.Length, -one_of(row))
```

Expected output:

```
tmp <- iris %>% select(-c(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) %>% unique() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% spread(Species, Sepal.Length)

cbind(setosa=unique(tmp$setosa), versicolor=unique(tmp$versicolor), virginica=unique(tmp$virginica))
#       setosa versicolor virginica
#  [1,]    5.1        7.0       6.3
#  [2,]    4.9        6.4       5.8
#  [3,]    4.7        6.9       7.1
#  [4,]    4.6        5.5       6.5
#  [5,]    5.0        6.5       7.6
#  [6,]    5.4        5.7       4.9
#  [7,]    4.4        6.3       7.3
#  [8,]    4.8        4.9       6.7
#  [9,]    4.3        6.6       7.2
# [10,]    5.8        5.2       6.4
# [11,]    5.7        5.0       6.8
# [12,]    5.2        5.9       5.7
# [13,]    5.5        6.0       7.7
# [14,]    4.5        6.1       6.0
# [15,]    5.3        5.6       6.9
# [16,]    5.1        6.7       5.6
# [17,]    4.9        5.8       6.2
# [18,]    4.7        6.2       6.1
# [19,]    4.6        6.8       7.4
# [20,]    5.0        5.4       7.9
# [21,]    5.4        5.1       5.9
```

Comment: Not sure why you have NAs in your desired output. Each `Species` value has 50 observations. What you were missing is to create `row` for each `Species` value separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbl_df(iris) %>%
  select(Species, Sepal.Length) %>%       # select columns of interest
  group_by(Species) %>%                   # for each value
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%           # create a row identifier
  spread(Species, Sepal.Length)           # reshape dataset

# # A tibble: 50 x 4
#       id setosa versicolor virginica
#  * <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1    5.1        7.0       6.3
# 2     2    4.9        6.4       5.8
# 3     3    4.7        6.9       7.1
# 4     4    4.6        5.5       6.3
# 5     5    5.0        6.5       6.5
# 6     6    5.4        5.7       7.6
# 7     7    4.6        6.3       4.9
# 8     8    5.0        4.9       7.3
# 9     9    4.4        6.6       6.7
# 10    10   4.9        5.2       7.2
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

Be extra careful of how you create/use your row identifier. The code above just uses the order of the dataset. If you re-order it somehow, you're going to get different row combinations. Check the code below:

```
tbl_df(iris) %>%
  arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>%         # order your values descending
  select(Species, Sepal.Length) %>%       # select columns of interest
  group_by(Species) %>%                   # for each value
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%           # create a row identifier
  spread(Species, Sepal.Length)           # reshape dataset

# # A tibble: 50 x 4
#      id setosa versicolor virginica
# * <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1    5.8        7.0       7.9
# 2     2    5.7        6.9       7.7
# 3     3    5.7        6.8       7.7
# 4     4    5.5        6.7       7.7
# 5     5    5.5        6.7       7.7
# 6     6    5.4        6.7       7.6
# 7     7    5.4        6.6       7.4
# 8     8    5.4        6.6       7.3
# 9     9    5.4        6.5       7.2
# 10    10   5.4        6.4       7.2
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

The `arrange(desc.))`, which is the difference from before, will make sure that you have the higher values on top rows (descending order).

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer(+1). was missing `group_by(Species)`!

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :-) I'd suggest you change/modify your desired output in your example so people don't get confused when they see your question and the answer. (i.e. correct those NA values).