# Tidyr::spread() error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys

Tags: r

I am learning tidyr and doing a small exercise to transform `iris` data set from wide to long.

The original data set:

```
   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

The resulting data set I want:

```
  Species  Part Length Width
1  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
2  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
3  setosa Petal    1.3   0.2
4  setosa Petal    1.5   0.2
5  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
6  setosa Petal    1.7   0.4
```

The code I wrote for manipulating data set:

```
iris_re <- iris[,c(5,1,2,3,4)]

iris.wide <- iris_re %>% 
  gather(key = "flower_att", value = "measurement",
         -Species) %>%
  separate(flower_att, into = c("Part","Method")) %>%
  spread(Method,measurement)
```

But the final line of `spread()` gives me an error:

> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 400 rows:

I did not expect this happen and I am still struggling with it. Thank you!

Comment: Without any identifiers, your script won't know how to put rows together. If you search the error message, you should see a lot of SO posts getting around this (the newer `pivot_wider` alternative helps), including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47351039/5325862) on the same dataset

Comment: @camille OK. I will read the link and try some small examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`, which can also take multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
iris_re %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species, names_to = c("Part", ".value"), names_sep= "[.]") %>%
  head
#  Species  Part Length Width
#1  setosa Sepal    5.1   3.5
#2  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
#3  setosa Sepal    4.9   3.0
#4  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
#5  setosa Sepal    4.7   3.2
#6  setosa Petal    1.3   0.2
```

---

The error in `spread` can occur when there are more than one unique combinations exist.  With `pivot_wider`, it is now replaced with a warning and would return a `list` column if there are duplicates and then we can `unnest`.   Or another way is to create a sequence column grouped by the column identifier that have duplicates to make a unique row identifier i.e.

```
iris_re %>% 
  gather(key = "flower_att", value = "measurement",
         -Species) %>%
  separate(flower_att, into = c("Part","Method")) %>%
  group_by(Species, Part, Method) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  spread(Method,measurement)
```

Comment: Could you please explain more on "more than one unique combinations" by using `iris` data set?  Does this mean the combination values from `Species`, `Part` and `Method` columns(the resulting table after `separate()`function)?  I need to read docs and see examples about the new functions `pivot_wider/longer` . The syntax is different from old function `gather/spread`.

Comment: @Steve  After the `separate` step, if you check the `count(Species, Part, Method)` it will be more than 1 and `spread` needs a count of 1, otherwise, it won't know which value belongs to which row

Comment: @Steve Regarding `pivot_wider/longer`, it is more a generalized version of `gather/spread`.  Here, the `pivot_longer` doesn't need to do two reshape i.e. convertiing to 'long' and then to 'wide'.  It does in a single step

Comment: Yes. The new function seems easier and more compatible. Thanks!